# Python primefinder doesn't work the way I want it to

Tags: python

I wanted to create a primelist generator that checks if a number is divisible by any of the primes smaller than itself and if it is not, it gets appended to the primelist. But my program only returns funny lists like the one in the example:

```
primelist=[2]
for m in range (10):
    for k in primelist:
        if m%k == 0 :
            continue
        else:
            primelist.append(m)
print (primelist)
```

printed list:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Look at the output, read through the code, and step through it line by line (in your head, on paper, or using e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/) - it should be very obvious exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a flag to check all numbers, you append too early currently. Try this:

```
primelist=[2]
for m in range (2,12):
    for k in primelist:
        if m%k == 0 :
            break
    else:
        primelist.append(m)
print (primelist)
```

Comment: You don't need to set a `flag`, just use for `for: else:` construct.

Comment: Thanks, that's more pythonic

Comment: change to: for m in [x+2 for x in range(10)]: otherwise everything is divisible by 1, and nothing else will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding each number each time ANY number in primelist gives remainder different than 0 (f.e. `4%3 !=0` so it appends). Instead you want to append it only if it gives remainder different than 0 for ALL prime numbers

```
primelist = [2]
for m in range(10):
    if all([m%i != 0 for i in primelist]): #If all remainders are different than 0 is prime
        primelist.append(m)
print(primelist)
```

This is not optim. A better algorithm could be

```
primelist = [2]

def isPrime(num):
    from math import sqrt
    for p in primelist:
        if p > int(sqrt(num)+1): #Just test until sqrt(num)
            return True
        elif num%p == 0:
            return False
    return True

primelist = [2]
for m in range(3, numberWanted):
    if isPrime(m):
        primelist.append(m)
print(primelist)
```

This way `isPrime` is lazy function that doesn't need to test against each primer number (Which could be useful for large numbers)

Edit: Full `isPrime` function:

```
def isPrime(num):
    from math import sqrt
    for p in range(2, int(sqrt(num)+1)):
        if num%p==0:
            return False
    return True
```

The problem with this function is that for large numbers it will test against the full range [2 - sqrt(num)], the previous function just tests against previously calculated prime numbers (`primelist`). The first one is only useful if you are populating `primelist` in order

Comment: Thanks.Though for me the position of "return True" in the second code block raises an error(but that is easily rectified). And the range for m should start for a number that is greater than or equal to 2 (otherwise it will append 1 to the primelist as it was mentioned in a comment to the other answer).

Comment: I think it's still not correct. The "isprime" function will always return true. But with the 'if all' method in the first code block it can be made working.

Comment: It works for me :S. Keep in mind that the `isPrime` function only tests against numbers in `primeList` (You can't test it without populating `primelist`). I'll edit with full `isPrime` function

Comment: It works with the second isprime function, but I think you should delete the first one, because that doesn't return the required primelist.